# Why this text with larger font size doesn't respect the line-height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertical align a text inside a div 100px by 100px. The problem is that when I set its font-size bigger, it doesn't respects the line-height.

Making another test but with the different font-size(12px) works.

How do I fix that and why this happens?

Bigger font size: http://jsfiddle.net/2sLNy/1/

Small font size: http://jsfiddle.net/2sLNy/2/

Bigger font size code:

```
div{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}

div:hover:before{
    opacity: 1;
}

div:before{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    content: " + ";
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is actually working as expected. Take a look at this for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/2sLNy/9/

The `+` is naturally positioned lower relative to all other letters. It has an offset. You should see that in the jsfiddle. The reason why it looks good when it's small is because, well, it's small and you can't see the offset as much as when the text is bigger.

Try using one of the icon fonts like [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) and using the following content property:

```
content: "\f067";
```

**Edit:** Not ideal, but this is what it looks like with fontawesome: http://jsfiddle.net/2sLNy/13/